# Почему не получается создать базу данных в SQLiteStudio?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

При создании бд выходит ошибка:

```
Не удалось добавить базу данных /Users/User/Desktop/bot/database: Невозможно открыть базу данных: unable to open database file
```

Что же делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Проверьте, что база данных не используется другим процессом

Comment: Не используется, это первая база

Comment: Можете пожалуйста приложить контекст того, как вы "открывайте" вашу базу данных?

Comment: Захожу в SQLiteStudio и нажимаю "Добавить базу данных", выбираю нужную директорию. А бд просто не создается, и выходит ошибка

Comment: пропрозвучит банально, но перезагрузите пк...

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Все так же не удается..((

Comment: Следовательно я могу судить о том, что либо путь до файла бд как-то неправильно указан, либо сам файл бд поврежден, попробуйте переместить его

Comment: все получилось, проблема с файлом была